# Server agent is running in linux machine were services are running on different ports how can we get the cpu utilized on different ports?

Tags: jmeter-plugins

In jmeter, Server agent is running with IP XXX.XXX.X.XXX. Linux machine were services are running on different ports. How can we get the CPU utilized on different ports and can we configure that in jmeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get CPU usage per process on a Linux host you can use [EXEC metric](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMonMetrics/#EXEC)

```
ps -p <pid of process one> -o %cpu
```

Example configuration:

[image: JMeter PerfMon Per Process CPU]

References:

- [ps command manual](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ps1.html)
- [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)